# Tomcat Connection Debug

Tags: tomcat

How can I identify why Tomcat 6.0 running within Eclipse is able to receive data from a port 80 connection via IIS7.5 and running Tomcat 6.0 standalone will not?
I have been through many forums and have verified my configuration and setup of Tomcat, IIS, isapi_redirect.dll, etc. So far no solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using two *very* ancient technologies.  Tomcat 6 is at end of life and IIS 7.5 isn't supported for production.

Comment: I realize that. The problem is the Eclipse/Tomcat is running in a production environment. I would like to get it running standalone with  Tomcat. The reason is I would like to have a solution that can auto start when the production server is rebooted. Now I have to manually start Eclipse and the Tomcat server after a reboot. Also I do  not want to break what is running in production. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like production is already broken.